# Complex routes with constraints

Tags: phoenix-framework

Assuming I have a travel agency application with this resource:

```
mix phx.gen.html Flights Flight flights departure destination 
                                starts_on ends_on 
                                flight_number price:integer
```

I want to display all flights which match a requesting URL in an index template. But I want to have that available with a kayak.com like route: http://localhost:4000/flights/FRA-MIA/2017-12-01/2017-12-08

In the official doc at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html I can't find an example of something similar to this. I need `FRA`, `MIA`, `2017-12-01` and `2017-12-08` as parameters.

The generated route is this:

```
resources "/flights", FlightController
```

I guess I could use the `get_flight!/1` function to split the `id` but that feels dirty. Is there a better way?

In Ruby on Rails I'd use something like `match "/flights/:from-:destination/:year(/:month(/:day))..." => "flights#index", :constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ }`

How can I tackle this problem in Phoenix?

Answer (score 0):

**lib/xyz_web/router.ex**

```
get "/flights/:departure/:destination/:starts_on/:ends_on", PageController, :index
```

Will result in this:

```
[info] GET /flights/FRA/MIA/2017-12-01/2017-12-08
[debug] Processing with XyzWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"departure" => "FRA", "destination" => "MIA", 
  "ends_on" => "2017-12-08", "starts_on" => "2017-12-01"}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
```

Of course that is without the constraints.

The controller:

```
def index(conn, %{"starts_on" => starts_on, "ends_on" => ends_on, 
                  "departure" => departure, 
                  "destination" => destination }) do
  what_ever = ...
  render(conn, "index.html", what_ever: what_ever)
end
```